Is this sub-exponential time less than quadratic time in the quadratic sieve?
The L-Notation is defined as:
$$L_n[\alpha,c]=e^{(c+O(1))\ln(n)^\alpha\ln^2(n)^{1-\alpha}}$$
As such, the Quadratic Sieve complexity is defined to be:
$$L_n[1/2,1]=e^{(1+O(1))\sqrt{\ln(n)\ln^2(n)}}$$
But i don't get exactly what this represents in O-notation. More specifically, I woud want to know if the quadratic sieve has sub-quadratic running times, this is, wether the inequality:
$$L_n[1/2,1]\leq O(n^2)$$
Holds for large enough $n$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Usually in factorization algorithms $n$ is the number to be factored, so the problem size and complexity is measured as a function of $\ln n$, since $\log_2 n$ is the length in bits of the number.
Because of this, $O(n)$ algorithms like trial divison use exponential time, even $O(\sqrt{n})$ (improved trial division) and any $O(n^c)$ with $c > 0$. When the complexity is writen as a function of the length it is clear: $O(n^c) = O(e^{c \ln n})$.
With $L_n[\alpha,c]$, only $\alpha = 0$ makes it polynomial in the length of $n$: $L_n[0,c] = O(e^{(c+o(1)) \ln \ln n}) = O((\ln n)^{c+o(1)})$.  On the other hand, $\alpha = 1$ is for pure exponential functions: $L_n[1,c] = O(e^{(c+o(1)) \ln n})$, so the quadratic sieve is in the middle of polynomial and exponential (in the $L$-notation sense).
